# ASP.NET MVC checkbox with Name attribute for corresponding value fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My Model

```
public class MyFormField
{
    public List<MyClass> propName { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Am passing **List of MyFormField** to view

In View

```
@foreach (var item in Model.propName)
 {

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
 }
```

i need to add a checkBox before  the textBox  like below

```
@foreach (var item in Model.propName)
 {
 @Html.checkbox("")
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
 }
```

and each checkbox should have a unique name attribute as a corresponding textbox. How can i Change my model to acheive this ?

For business need i need a checkbox for each corresponding Textbox or what better way i can achieve in MVC ?

Comment: I did write an answer but now I don't understand what you want. What do you mean by *and each checkbox should have a unique name attribute as a corresponding textbox*?

Comment: @Liam i need to associate checkbox  with corresponding textbox . will i get a unique name property for all checkboxes similar to textbox  ?

Comment: what do you mean by associate? Your intentions are not clear at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to your model:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public boolean Checked {get;set;}
}
```

Then add:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.Checked)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.Name)
```

That way, each checkbox is assoicated with the `MyClass` in the list

Comment: But how does the checkbox is associated with textbox will i get a unique name propert for all checkboxes ??

Comment: Yeah you should do, try it out :) . The model binder needs to know where to bind that value to, so it will create this unqiue identifier in order to make sure the value gets binded back to the right property

Comment: i did tried. Am getting item.Checked as Name Attribute for all check boxes. Am i doing smthin wrong ?

Comment: The only other way I would do it, would be to use JsonConvert.Serialize to serialize your list of objects. Then have knockout take care of the rest. when I'm done I would use knockout to assign the modified json to a hidden element and submit it back to the controller for deserializing!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public boolean Checked {get;set;}
}
```

Doing this you would have unique id for each row.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.propName.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.propName[i].Checked, new { class = "propName_" + i })
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.propName[i].Name, new { class = "propName_" + i })
}
```

Comment: That would produce two elements on the form with the same Id, [which is illegal](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20140311/H93)

Comment: You'd be better off doing the same and removing the id bit. Then it would be fine as checked and name would have different id's but still contain the index

Comment: @Liam: oh! common. It was just an idea. can't he change class or name instead of id. Since the main idea is how one can relate checkbox to textbox.

Comment: I'm sorry but this solution should not be encouraged. If your going to do a job, you should do it properly. This will produce illegal syntax which btw breaks several technologies including JQuery and Angular...Instead of arguing with me you could simply edit your answer?

Comment: Setting the `name` to the same value is even worse! now it won't post the correct values when the form post's! You'll now have form values `propName_1=true&propName_1=name`. Which one does it use?!